# python nodes not running

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the `talker_publisher.py` code in programming robots with ROS book , I have written the code just as the example in the book but it gives me this error :

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘pyton’: No such file or directory
```

though I have python 2.7 installed so what's wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284489/python-nodes-not-running/) by [karim](https://answers.ros.org/users/34014/karim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> /usr/bin/env: ‘pyton’: No such file or directory
> ```

If this is a direct copy-paste from your Python script, then I believe you're missing an `h` there.

The name of the Python interpreter binary is `python`, not `pyton`.

Change the first line of your script (where I'm assuming you specify the Python interpreter) to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and things should start working.

Note that this is not a ROS problem at all. In the future, please try to search (using Google fi) for these kind of problems. That way you don't have to wait for someone from this forum to answer you, and you have a much larger community (ie: the entire internet) to help you instead of just the ROS community.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karim](https://answers.ros.org/users/34014/karim/) on 2018-03-06**:
this indeed was the problem , excuse my noob-ness :)